# What exactly happens when I use the return value of a void function (by casting a function pointer)?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, undefined-behavior

When I run the following program, it *always* prints "yes". However when I change `SOME_CONSTANT` to `-2` it *always* prints "no". Why is that? I am using visual studio 2019 compiler with optimizations disabled.

```
#define SOME_CONSTANT -3

void func() {
    static int i = 2;
    int j = SOME_CONSTANT;
    i += j;
}

void main() {
    if (((bool(*)())func)()) {
        printf("yes\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("no\n");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the output assembly of `func` (*IDA Pro 7.2*):

```
sub     rsp, 18h
mov     [rsp+18h+var_18], 0FFFFFFFEh
mov     eax, [rsp+18h+var_18]
mov     ecx, cs:i
add     ecx, eax
mov     eax, ecx
mov     cs:i, eax
add     rsp, 18h
retn
```

Here is the first part of `main`:

```
sub     rsp, 628h
mov     rax, cs:__security_cookie
xor     rax, rsp
mov     [rsp+628h+var_18], rax
call    ?func@@YAXXZ    ; func(void)
test    eax, eax
jz      short loc_1400012B0
```

Here is main decompiled:

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  int v3; // eax

  func();
  if ( v3 )
    printf("yes\n");
  else
    printf("no\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Short answer: Undefined behavior. Longer answer: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius But it *always* prints "yes" and "no" respectively.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. The program might as well erase your hard drive

Comment: @super Doesn't matter. If it invokes undefined behavior - anything can happen.

Comment: this c++ code does not make much sense. You need to look at the assembly to understand what is going on

Comment: The assembly of main is where you would see what is happening

Comment: I am not fluent at assembly but I suppose also `main` is required to get the full picture

Comment: `eax` is used for return values in some conventions, and it happens to keep the last `i` value when `func` exits.

Comment: It might be interesting to speculate about UB personally, but it is not for SO. Check the assembly to see what your compiler did, and check its source code to see why it might've done that. Also, `main()` returns `int`.

Comment: Most likely there `bool` is returned in a register. And the function makes use of the same register for the value computation, before assigning to `i` at its location. The function returns with the "correct" register holding a value.

Comment: @super By telling your compiler to return `void`, you have yet another kind of UB. Hence the code can do anything, and it's not fruitful to discuss.

Comment: @underscore_d not sure if it is "not for SO", rather it is not so much for the `C++` tag but rather for `assembly`

Comment: This question was tagged with `undefined behavior` by OP for a reason.

Comment: So function uses register eax for its computation results. Main uses eax in the if to determine if it needs to jump. So the logic of the if follows what happens in the function.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature :D

Comment: @PeterCordes what uninitialized variable?

Comment: @idclev463035818: Oops, fixed.  I had been looking at the decompiled code block, not the original source.  That makes more sense; a debug build would probably have loaded from memory when reading a variable even if it was uninitialized, and thus would have read it as `0xcccccccc` because MSVC debug mode poisons that stack frame with `0xcc` bytes, exactly so that read-uninitialized is easy to detect.

Comment: Read Lattner's [blog on UB](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What apparently happened is:

```
mov     ecx, cs:i
add     ecx, eax
mov     eax, ecx   ; <- final value of i is stored in eax
mov     cs:i, eax  ; and then also stored in i itself
```

Different registers could have been used, it just happened to work this way. There is nothing about the code that forces `eax` to be chosen. That `mov eax, ecx` is really redundant, `ecx` could have been stored straight to `i`. But it happened to work this way.

And in `main`:

```
call    ?func@@YAXXZ    ; func(void)
test    eax, eax
jz      short loc_1400012B0
```

`rax` (or part of it, like `eax` or `al`) is used for the return value for integer-ish types (such as booleans) in the WIN64 ABI, so that makes sense. That means the final value of `i` happens to be used as the return value, by accident.

Comment: This looks like (partly?) un-optimized compiler output, otherwise even MSVC would be able to optimize away most or all of the `func` function body.  So that explains the redundant `mov eax, ecx`; the compiler wasn't even trying.  Strange that it didn't set up RBP as a frame pointer in a debug build, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes it is unoptimized as OP indicates, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MK-joC) it is reproduced (the optimized version subtract straight from `i` without polluting any registers)

Answer (score 7):

```
((bool(*)())func)()
```

This expression takes a pointer to `func`, casts the pointer to a different type of function, then invokes it.  Invoking a function through a pointer-to-function whose function signature does not match the original function is *undefined behavior* which means that anything at all might happen.  From the moment this function call happens, the behavior of the program cannot be reasoned about.  You cannot predict what will happen with any certainty.  Behavior might be different on different optimization levels, different compilers, different versions of the same compiler, or when targeting different architectures.

This is simply because the compiler is allowed to assume that you *won't* do this. When the compiler's assumptions and reality come into conflict, the result is a vacuum into which the compiler can insert whatever it likes.

The simple answer to your question "why is that?" is, quite simply: because it can.  But tomorrow it might do something else.

Comment: _From the moment this function call happens, the behavior of the program cannot be reasoned about._ It's worse than that even, [undefined behavior can cause time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) (by Raymond Chen).

Answer (score 3):

I always get printed out `no`, so it must be dependent from compiler to compiler, hence the best answer is UB (Undefined Behavior).